Second-order perturbations of gauge field in GR
When expanding a Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}[g_{\mu\nu},A_\mu,\chi]$ to second order in perturbations, the metric is expanded like
$$g_{\mu\nu}\to g_{\mu\nu}+\delta g_{\mu\nu}+\frac{1}{2}\delta g_{\mu}^{\,\alpha}\,\delta g_{\nu\alpha},$$
but how exactly does this work for the gauge field, is it like
$$A_\mu\to A_\mu+\delta A_\mu+\frac{1}{2}\delta A_\alpha\,\delta A^\alpha\,A_\mu? $$
